# C# - RichTextBoxPrintCtrl and tabcontrol

Tags: c#, printing, richtextbox, tabcontrol

Hello (and sorry for my English), I have a problem with Printing RTF using RichTextBoxPrintCtrl and TabControl.

1) The tabcontrol got no tabs on Design, when the Form Load, it will get a tab with the method `AddTab(Title)`. (Don't mind about other variables).

```
private void AddTab(string Name = "Nuova Nota*")
{
    RichTextBox Body = new RichTextBox();
    Body.Name = "Body";
    Body.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Body.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
    TabPage NewPage = new TabPage();
    string DocumentText = Nome;
    if (Nome == "Nuova Nota*")
    {
        TabCount += 1;
        DocumentText = Nome + TabCount;
    }
    NewPage.Name = DocumentText;
    NewPage.Text = DocumentText;
    tabControl1.Visible = true;
    NewPage.Controls.Add(Body);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(NewPage);
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = NewPage;
    Nomi_Files.Add(NewPage.Text);
    Path_Files.Add("");
}
```

2) Once the tab is created, you can start to write, change colors, fonts, etc...
To get access on the document that you are making, i use a `GetCurrentDocument` that return the "Body" of the selected tab:

```
private RichTextBox GetCurrentDocument
{
    get { return (RichTextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["Body"];}
}
```

Now, all the functions (save, open, fonts, colors...) Works Fine, i wanted to print my document and keep the style, so i Googled and i found this: [How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812425)

I made the `RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.dll`, added the resource on my project, added the item inside the toolbox, but i can't change the `RichTextBox` that i create from Code, with `RichTextBoxPrintCtrl`.
The error that i get is:

> Error 1   'RichTextBoxPrintCtrl' is a 'namespace' but is used like a
>   'type'

How i can use that `RichTextBoxPrintCtrl` without drag and drop it inside the design form?

Comment: Are you missing a `using RichTextBoxPrintCtrl;`?

Comment: Nope, already tryed that, nothing change still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured out how to solve it:

instead of declaring like:

```
RichTextBoxPrintCtrl NameControl = new RichTextBoxPrintCtrl();
```

we need to declare the namespace so:

```
RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl NameControl = new RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl();
```

Everything works fine :) thanks;